# Coroutine don't work second time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I have main menu through which I start new game (load another scene) and execute script below. But when I go back to the main menu and start new game again, script below doesn't work. I tried to stop coroutine inside Start function, but it doesn't helped

```
private IEnumerator OpenCloseEyesAnimation()
 {
     if (!isOpenEyesAnimationStarted)
     {
         isOpenEyesAnimationStarted = true;
         openCloseEyes.OpenCloseDoor(); // this work 1st and 2nd time
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(6.0f); // this line don't work 2nd time
         stepNumber++;
         isOpenEyesAnimationStarted = false;
     }
 }
```

I call it once inside Update function

[image]

Comment: Where are you calling this function?

Comment: if you open and close the menu with-in 6 seconds it wont (bool has not been reset yet) are you sure you either reset the boolean when you go to the main menu OR wait more than 6 seconds before going to the main menu?

Comment: @Nestoraj I call it in Update once

Comment: @ParadoxForge Lines before WaitForSeconds works and I wait for 6 seconds

Comment: @dima the first AND second time ?

Comment: @ParadoxForge Lines before WaitForSeconds works 1st and 2nd time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should need to use [StopCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) at proper place. Each time you startCoroutine, stop it first.

```
 private IEnumerator OpenCloseEyesAnimation()
     {
         if (!isOpenEyesAnimationStarted)
         {

             isOpenEyesAnimationStarted = true;
             openCloseEyes.OpenCloseDoor();
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(6.0f); // this line don't work after second launch
             stepNumber++;
             isOpenEyesAnimationStarted = false;
         }
     }
```

As Commment mention(@Paradox Forge) Update your UpdateEvent code:

```
case 3: 
  StopCoroutine(OpenCloseEyesAnimation());
  isOpenEyesAnimationStarted = false;
  StartCoroutine(OpenCloseEyesAnimation());
```

Comment: this will not work if `isOpenEyesAnimationStarted` is still set to `true` when it is called a second time

Comment: no, it don't helped and isOpenEyesAnimationStarted = false. Line before WaitForSeconds works in the second time

Comment: @dima this did help?

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan sorry, I'll try it in a few minutes

Comment: When I enabled pause menu to go to the main menu, I've made Time.timeScale = 0. And it was == 0 after second launch. That was the problem)